# What is the mathematics of android’s postTranslate

Tags: android, math, matrix

Say I have the matrix

```
a  b  c
d  e  f
0  0  1
```

if I do `matrix.postTranslate(x,y);` What math takes place?

Comment: the doc says `Postconcats the matrix with the specified translation. M' = T(dx, dy) * M`

Comment: yeah, I don't know what that means :)

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

> Postconcats the matrix with the specified translation. M' = T(dx, dy) * M

`T(dx, dy)` is a [translation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29#Matrix_representation), so it looks like:

```
1 0 x     a b c
0 1 y  *  d e f
1 1 1     0 0 1
```

So in your case the result would be:

```
a   b   (c + x)
d   e   (f + y)
a+d b+e (c+f+1)
```